# Descriptors : Precendence of Attribute access through __getattribute()__

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't understand what does the below precedence means in context of `__getattribute__()` special method and `Descriptors`

I read this under the `topic("Precedence") - under topic ("Desriptors")` from book [Core Python Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132269937) 3 times, still can't get through it.. Can any one explain what are these precedence, and where they are used for??

- Class attributes
- Data descriptors
- Instance attributes
- Non-data descriptors
- Defaulting to `__getattr__()`

I also read the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#more-attribute-access-for-new-style-classes), where I found the below statement: -

> For instance bindings, the precedence of descriptor invocation depends
>   on the which descriptor methods are defined. A descriptor can define
>   any combination of `__get__()`, `__set__()` and `__delete__()`. If it does
>   not define `__get__()`, then accessing the attribute will return the
>   descriptor object itself unless there is a value in the object’s
>   instance dictionary. If the descriptor defines `__set__()` and/or
>   `__delete__()`, it is a data descriptor; if it defines neither, it is a non-data descriptor. Normally, data descriptors define both `__get__()`
>   and `__set__()`, while non-data descriptors have just the `__get__()`
>   method.
>
> Data descriptors with `**__set__()**` and `**__get__()**` defined always override
>   a redefinition in an instance dictionary. In contrast, non-data
>   descriptors can be overridden by instances.
>
> Python methods (including `staticmethod()` and `classmethod()`) are
>   implemented as non-data descriptors. Accordingly, instances can
>   redefine and override methods. This allows individual instances to
>   acquire behaviors that differ from other instances of the same class.

Can anyone give a small example to explain what the `first paragraph` is all about?
Also what does it mean by saying - `override a redefinition in an instance dictionary`??

Comment: Related: [Which Python language rule allows the descriptor to be found first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865902/), [Descriptors and python-provided attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536539/)

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost.. Thanks Piotr for those links.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have a class:

```
class C(object):
    dd = MyDataDescriptor()
    ndd = MyNonDataDescriptor()
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = 1
```

Let's look first at data descriptors. If in your code you do:

```
cobj = C()
cobj.dd
```

accordingly to the above paragraph, the `cobj.__dict__` object will be always *overriden* when the `dd` attribute is accessed, i.e.`__get__/__set__/__del__` methods of the descriptor object will always be used instead of the dictionary. The only exception occurs when the descriptor object doesn't define a `__get__` method. Then if there is a `dd` key in the `cobj.__dict__` object its value will be read, if not the descriptor object itself will be returned.

Now for the non-data descriptors. If in your code you call:

```
cobj.ndd = 2
```

then the `cobj.__dict__` *hides* the non-data descriptor and the `ndd` attribute is always read from the `cobj.__dict__` object. So if you do:

```
cobj.ndd
```

the `__get__` method of the descriptor will not be called. But if you delete the attribute from the dictionary:

```
del cobj.ndd
```

then the descriptor is back, so calling

```
cobj.ndd
```

will call the `__get__` method on the descriptor.

Comment: Thank you soo much Vicent, for such a nice and elaborate explanation.. All my doubts are clear now.. Thank you again :)